# Is it possible to capitalize first letter of text/string in react native? How to do it?

Tags: text, react-native, react-native-text

I have to capitalize first letter of text that i want to display. I searched for it but i cant found clear thing to do that, also there is no such props for `text` in react native official documentation.

I am showing my text with following format:

```
<Text style={styles.title}>{item.item.title}</Text>
```

or

```
<Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.title}</Text>
```

How can I do it?

Suggestions are welcome?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Write a function like this

```
Capitalize(str){
return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}
```

then call it from `<Text>` tag By passing text as parameter

```
<Text>{this.Capitalize(this.state.title)} </Text>
```

Comment: How can it possible using style sheet,

Comment: How about every word in the text input?

Comment: @VarunChandran use `textTransform: 'capitalize'`. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58867901/7869175

Comment: @FernandoRojo your answer is wrong as it will capitalize the first letter of **every** word in a sentence

Answer (score 65):

You can also use the `text-transform` css property in style:

```
<Text style={{textTransform: 'capitalize'}}>{this.state.title}</Text>
```

Comment: This only works for all lower case text.
(1) If you have "heLLo", this will turn the text into "HeLLo".
(2) If you want "Hello" as a result, you can use `"heLLo".toLowerCase()` with `textTransform: 'capitalize'` css.

Comment: This will capitalize every word in the input. Which might be OK, but the OP asks only for capitalization of the first letter.

Answer (score 38):

React native now lets you make text uppercase directly with `textTransform: 'capitalize'`. No function necessary.

```js
import { Text } from 'react-native'

// will render as Hello!
export const Caps = () => {
  return <Text style={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}>hello!</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Instead of using a function, a cleaner way is to write this as a common component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const CapitalizedText = (props) => {
  let text = props.children.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + props.children.slice(1, props.children.length);

  return (
      <View>
        <Text {...props}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
  );
};

export default CapitalizedText;
```

Wherever you're using `<Text>`, replace it with `<CapitalizedText>`

Answer (score 9):

just use javascript.

`text.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1, text.length)`

Comment: I used it but i have to write it for every `text` tag i have used. can i call a function in `text` tag by passing parameter as that text and all other text can be capitalize by using that function.

Comment: i think you mean `<Text>{autoCapitalize(text)}`</Text>. Sure you can do that

Comment: `<Text>{this.autoCapitalize(text)}</Text>` this is write

Comment: @mayureshpatil: I am getting on error on your suggestion too.

Comment: @mayureshpatil It gives error that autpCapitalize(text) is not a function

Comment: Isn't this exactly instead (reducing in 1 the length)?


text.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1, text.length - 1) I might be wrong : )

Answer (score 3):

**TextInput have this to handle using**

```
autoCapitalize enum('none', 'sentences', 'words', 'characters')
```

**for example try like this**

```
<TextInput
     placeholder=""
     placeholderTextColor='rgba(28,53,63, 1)'
     autoCapitalize = 'none'
     value ='test'
     />
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me!

```
labelStyle:{
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
        fontSize:20,

      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is very general functionality I put it in a file called `strings.js` under my library:

```
// lib/strings.js

export const CapitalizeFirstLetter = (str) => {
  return str.length ? str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1) : str
}
```

And simply import it in the components that need it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { CapitalizeFirstLetter} from 'lib/strings'

export default function ComponentWithCapitalizedText() {

  return <Text>CapitalizeFirstLetter("capitalize this please")</Text>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added a prototype function, based on @mayuresh answer

```
String.prototype.Capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
myStr.Capitalize()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capitalize only the first letter of the input:

```js
function CapitalizeFirstLetterOfInput () {

const onInputUppercase = (e) => {
    let firstLetter = e.target.value.charAt(0);
    e.target.value = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + e.target.value.slice(1);
  };
  
return (
  <div>
 <input onInput={onInputUppercase}/>
  </div>
)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*if anyone interested doing it by just css/style*

<strong style={{textTransform: 'capitalize'}}>{props.alert.type}!

> here inner {} is for object {textTransform: 'capitalize'}

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me:

```
text.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1, text.length)
```

I used it with a props in an *alt* tag:

```
`${(props.image).slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + (props.image).slice(1, (props.image).length)}`
```

Then I guess you can apply that to any text you want.